# how to draw with UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()

Tags: ios, ios5, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

Im trying to generate an image, and have found UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() in the Apple docs which looks perfect. Ive been looking at some Quartz tutorials and in each one they use a custom view to do their drawing which doesn't seem necessary in this case, but i dont know enough to be sure. Whats the best way to do my drawing using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you probably want to use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` and `scale`=0.0 to get resolution independence, but yes, once you call the function the frameworks will have set up a normal graphics context you can use as in the tutorials. You can get at it with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`.

When you have finished drawing you will likely want to use `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`to actually capture what you have drawn.

And don't forget to call `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` when finished.

Comment: how would i use scale to get resolution independence?

Comment: See the docs for UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions() - setting scale = 0.0 tells Core Graphics to choose a device-appropriate scale factor, giving resolution independence on the current device.